# div display inline hidden

Tags: javascript, html, inline, hidden

I am defining a template as follows:

```
 $.template('aTemplate',
  '<div id="someid" class="abc">' +
   ....
  '</div>'
);
```

I want this div to be inline with other elements ( wherever I place them). 
I also want this div to be hidden ( when I add it to DOM) and then become visible on some other action( user click).

So to make it inline and hidden, I define following css

```
.abc {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

and on some action, I have

```
 $('#someid').show()
```

But it does not seems to work. Any suggestions as to what can be corrected?

Comment: Try `$('#someid').css('visibility','visible')`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `$.show()` will set `display:inline-block`

**From the docs:**
http://api.jquery.com/show/
The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

If you want the div to maintain it's position in the DOM, try setting its opacity to 0 to start:

```
.abc {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then call:

```
$('#someid').css('opacity','1');
```

Comment: It kind of works. The problem is my div contains some buttons also. Just setting the opacity to 0 does not make sure that if someone clicks in that area the button clicks wont fire, so I need to disable and hide

Comment: I would not use opacity to show and hide something. Clicks will register, not user friendly, don't do it.